API GET request file size too long gives 400 error
I tried to connect to the Steam Market API for price history and took for example:
https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20|%20Safari%20Mesh%20(Field-Tested)
but I'm pretty sure that because the output text is too long (156.68 KB) I got the 400 error.
I tried to expand the query string and content length in web.config like this:
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" maxQueryString="300024" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

and marked request filtering in my IIS:

but nothing changed and I still get the 400 error. My web browser is Chrome and I tried also in Internet Explorer and Opera.
My site is in ASP.NET and my http request in C#.
